# My Firebase realtime database security rules: validate not working

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {

    "interviews": {
      ".read": true,
        ".write": "auth != null && root.child('admins').child(auth.uid).exists()",
        "thumbnail" :{
          ".validate" : "newData.val() != 0 || (newData.val() == 0 && data.val() == 'uploading')"
        },
        "soundbyte" :{
          ".validate" : "newData.val() != 0 || (newData.val() == 0 && data.val() == 'uploading')"
        }
    },
    "token": {
      ".read": false,
      ".write": "auth != null && auth.isAdmin == true"
    },
    "admins":{
      ".read" : false,
      ".write":  "auth != null && auth.isAdmin == true" 
    }
  }
}
```

Can you tell any problem with my security rules, as I am trying to add a validation to my thumbnail's data.

Here is a little data structure example I am gonna use with it.

```
interviews
 -K_l_pkOTUYovqRwajln
       detail: "YO"
       soundbyte: "interview_sb_KlpkOTUYovqRwajln.mp3"
       thumbnail: "uploading"
       title: "Episode Five"
       video_url: ""
 -K_ll31srQ46vgtDXX1n
       detail: "Duncan lives in a town."
       soundbyte: "interview_sb_KllsrQvgtDXXn.mp3"
       thumbnail: "interview_thumb_KllsrQvgtDXXn.jpg"
       title: "Duncan"
       video_url: ""
```

Comment: It seems a little weird to be using a number (`0`) and a string (`'uploading'`) as values for the same property. What's that reasoning behind that? The question would be clearer if you provided examples of the types of data you'd be writing and what you'd be expecting the rules to enforce.

Comment: What are the rules supposed the enforce? The validate rules allow for anything other than zero to be written and zero can be written if the previous value was `unloading`. So in what way do the rules "not work"?

Comment: Yes, it seems right here, but while playing in simulator, its not giving desired result. That's why I asked if anyone can see any mistakes here.